# Adding a big list to ion select makes app slow

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a large number of list in my ion-options, which makes my view very slow, if I add 4 items in ion-option my view in my mobile works fast, but when I add a large number of list in my html file the app slows down,

```
<ion-item>
                <ion-label style="color: black;" >Country</ion-label>
                <ion-select name="Country" placeholder="select a Country" [(ngModel)]="Country" required>
                    <ion-option value="United States">United States</ion-option>
                    <ion-option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</ion-option>
                    <ion-option value="Albania">Albania</ion-option>
                    <ion-option value="Algeria">Algeria</ion-option>
                .
                ./* list of all countries are needed */
                .                    
                </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
```

Is there any possibilities to load all countries and make the app to work fast.
Totally we have 196 country in world, what should I do to load everything

Comment: is your ion-options data are dynamic ? if so can show your .ts file code so that will help

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've searched on the internet I found no real, straightforward answer to this problem.

However *daveshirman* gives a good suggestion on [ionic's github issue section](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/10087):

> Why don't you change your select to a modal window popup with a search
>   field which has the list in a virtual list component. Add a search
>   field and a pipe filter too.

Answer (score -3):

Try it

```
  <ion-label>Country</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="Country" placeholder="select a Country">
        <ion-option value={{item.val}} *ngFor="let item of options">{{item.name}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

.ts

```
    public val;
    public options =  [
              {
                "name": "United States",
                "val" : "United States"
              },
              {
                "name": "Afghanistan",
                "val" : "Afghanistan"
              },
              {
                "name": "Albania",
                "val" : "Albania"
              },
              {
                "name": "Algeria",
                "val" : "Algeria"
              }

            ];
```

Comment: i have a list of around 100 countries when i try to load using your method my app goes slow, where if i load 4 its fast @fongfuse

Comment: This is the standard way to create a ion-select, but it doesn't answer the question.